# reload page after login via wp-login.php popup by thickbox

Tags: wordpress, authentication, thickbox

I open wp-login.php in a popup, so I can login, but everything remains into the thickbox popup.
I want to close the popup and reload the page after the succesfull login but I've no idea about what I've to do.

Thanks

Comment: I deal with this problem using an hidden layer.
  On press a button who calls a logged in only service this layer appear and handle all login issues.